# 3d environments and managing them on iOS

Tags: 3d, coordinates

I would like to start learning 3d game development and currently only develop 2d games.

A few basic questions I am interested in are:

What is used to create the 3d environments? Are they all done in e.g. Maya, Lightwave, 3d modeling software?

What is the output format for these models and how are they manipulated in iOS? Is it all done using openGL(GL ES on iOS)?

e.g a monster needs to be spawned in the game world. What coordinates are used?

Are the concepts the same as 2d in terms of collision on the coordinates and movement on the coordinates of the game world?

How are 3d games managed in iOS on the low available memory. (e.g. FPS games)

Lastly, Can someone please recommend a good book that is up to date and can be applied to todays techniques.

Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to say you have multiple questions all mixed into one.

Comment: Agreed. It's generally better if you split your questions up and ask each question on it's own. You are likely to get better answers that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer some:

Yes, modelling is being done in a modelling software. Tho you can generate meshes programatically too. Or you can write the model files using a text editor :) So basically you use some 3d software like Max, Maya or Blender.

The output depends on the software used. E.g. Max has the .max format. But usually you can export your models into some common formats like .obj. If you want to write a 3d game engine from the ground up, then you'd have to write the code that loads these formats. It's quite tedious, but that's the reason people use libraries for these (or complete game engines...).

World coordinates are used for spawning things into the world :) Check out some books on 3d.

I'd recommend checking out some available 3d engines, to try things out and understand the concepts better. Ogre or Unity is a good start I think. I can't recommend any books, there're thousands on this topics regarding your questions (most of them are rubbish tho). It's like you ask us to recommend you a book on mathematics. Be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Scythe. I will check out Ogre. Im aware of Unity. The book I was after was something that I could read to better my understanding of the concepts in 3d game programming and the used techniques.

Comment: You should check out UDK, they have added iOS support, and it's a very good game engine, with loads of features. Even though the learning curve is a little steep it's well worth checking out.

Comment: My thoughts on UDK is that on the artist side of things, all the tools are excellent. On the programmer's side though... not so much. Also, since you only get script access, you must know subclasses that you inherit from, making it extremely hard for the beginner. Personally, I think Unity is one of the easiest ways to get started in 3D programming.

Comment: Great. I will have a look. Are there good 3d art resources for beginners who want to try out 3d game programming?

Comment: Check out the official Unity tutorials, especially the 3d platofrmer tutorial. It has a full blown game, with art and stuff you can experiment with.

Comment: Tthe "only" problem with Unity is the price.